# Integral representation of a stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

If I have a stochastic differential equation gives as
$$
dX_t = aW_t^2dt
+bW_t^3dW_t$$
where $w_t$ is a wiener process and $a,b$ are real numbers. **How can I reach the integral representation of $X_t$?**
In other words how do I compute $f,g$ such that:

$$X_t=X_s+\int_s^tf(t,W_t)dt+\int_s^tg(t,W_t)dW_t
$$
when $t>s$

Comment: You just ... integrate, from $s$ to $t$...? I mean, its not like you will solve those integrals, but the representation is pretty much this.
As a result, your $f(t, W_t) = aW_t^2$ and $g(t, W_t) = bW_t^3$
Also, keep in mind, the $t$ should actually be something else, like $s$, since $t$ is in your limits of integration, so replace all $t$ with $s$